# Add/import certificate with password via command line Mac OS X

Tags: security, import, terminal, passwords, certificate

I'm trying to import a .pfx certificate via command line. This certificate is secured by a password. Is there a way to do this in terminal? I'm running OS X 10.8.

When I use this command I get the default pop-up asking for the password:

```
security import certificate.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

When I use this command:

```
security import certificate.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P password
```

I get this error:

```
SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)
```

I'm sure the password is  correct because it works if I enter it manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Got it!

The password starts with a dollar and I didn't escape it with a \.

So let's say the password is $tup1dP@ssw0rd the command has to be:

```
security import certificate.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P \$tup1dP@ssw0rd
```

Comment: This is great. In my case, I had to escape the `&` character. Thanks!

Comment: Another example to add to our 'never-use-these-characters-in-a-password' list. :)

Comment: How to then trust the imported certificate via the CLI?

Comment: The most fool proof way (on bash/zsh) is generally to wrap it in single quotes (`-P '$tup1dP@ssw0rd'`).  Unless the stupid password contains single quotes as well, they need to be "escaped" as `'\''`, e.g. `-P 'I love apostrophe'\''s'`